# Make screen take same proportion of screen independently of resolution

Tags: html, height, responsive

I would like for my website to take the whole page height and without scrolling bar. But if i set the height in px it will change depending on the screen resolution. How can I do it so that is takes the whole page independently of the screen resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the view height unit.

1vh is relative to 1% of the height of the viewport, so if you set it to 100 it will be exactly the height of the users viewport.

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help!! :)

Comment: Would be great if you could mark my answer as the solution